# htaccess url rewrite for userprofiles

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Every signed up member has an userprofile. The URL looks like: http://domain.com/content/profile/profile.php?username=USERNAMEOFTHEUSER

How do I rewrite it so it shows the URL as: http://domain.com/USERNAMEOFTHEUSER ?

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ content/profile/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it aint working and I have no htaccess knowledge.

**EDIT #1**

Also, my map structure looks like this:

```
content/example1/example_file1.php
content/example2/example_file2.php
content/example3/example_file3.php
```

How do I hide the content/examples/ maps? So that: domain.com/content/example2/example_file2.php

turns into domain.com/example_file2 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /content/profile/profile\.php\?username=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /content/profile/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: CORRECTION! Whenever I go to a file in the root, it shows an empty user profile.

Comment: That should only happen if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also like to remove the .php extension. WHenever I type in: domain.com/index.php the index page comes up. When I type in domain.com/index it shows an non-exisiting profile. Instead it should show the index. Same for any other page.

Comment: That is because since the username url is `example.com/somename` it will silently rewrite it. So if you try to remove the `.php` extension from the urls, how is it to know which is a username and which is a file?

Comment: Thats a good question, lmfao. Whats the best thing to do since I want to show the userprofiles via domain.com/userprofile? Work with subdomain(s) for non-profile pages? What about the index though..

Comment: You would do `domain.com/profile/userprofile` or if there aren't many non profile pages you could rewrite them before the profiles e.g. `RewriteRule ^hel$ /hel.php [L]` before the rewrite cond/rule.